# Styling the cursor with css

Tags: html, css, cursor

I know it's possible to use an image as the cursor, like this:

```
.module {
  cursor: url('path-to-image.png'), auto;   
}
```

Is it also possible to use a custom div element as the cursor or otherwise customize it with css properties? I'd like to use a triangle as shown [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/). Is that possible somehow?

How would one go about doing this?

Comment: I don't follow. What's this arrow-right thing? Got any visual examples?

Comment: Something like this: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/ I'm just talking about a pure css icon, that is done via css and not via an image. And I want to apply this icon as cusor.

Comment: Okay. Is that how you want the cursor to look like? Just the triangle?

Comment: Yeah, for instance! This is just an example. My actual icon is this: http://jsfiddle.net/vbvng3z0/3/

Comment: I don't think it's possible to use actual html-elements to be a cursor. Try creating an image instead and use that. The `cursor` property only takes one of the specific cursor-values, such as "pointer", or a URL to an image. However, it *might* be possible to do something in Javascript.

Comment: Is it possible to use jQuery for that and use a `div.classname` as a mouse-follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into this a bit, and while it's impossible to do with CSS, you can actually do this with jQuery.

You create a div and make it follow the cursor while also hiding the "normal" one, hence creating a bit of a cursor. It's a bit of a hack, as it's not actually a cursor, and it may or may not have some compatibility or functional problems.

Anyway, here's the code:

```js
$(document).bind('mousemove', function(e){
    $('#tail').css({
       left:  e.pageX + 1,
       top:   e.pageY
    });
});
```

```css
#tail {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 10px solid green;
}

* {
  cursor: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tail"></div>

<a href="http://google.com">Click me!</a>
```

I had to offset the cursor by one pixel (`e.pageX + 1`), otherwise the cursor-div would be directly below the cursor and you'd always be clicking on that instead of the object you actually want to click on.

Comment: Thanks, Chris. Can you try that with my icon example please. Cause for me this behaves really laggy. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/vbvng3z0/4/

Comment: A minor change: http://jsfiddle.net/vbvng3z0/6/ I also changed the offset so that the "click" happens on the tip of the arrow, instead of on its center.